# Change Price with range input

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am creating a pricing table and the price should change according to how many users will be registered. The testing site is https://fonexinc.com/price3.html
My question is how do I change the price according to the user range input with the amount of users they use, this is the price table: https://fonexinc.com/standard-pricing-structure/

I use this input range from codepen: https://codepen.io/yavuzselim/pen/qZJQra

Code for the price

```
<div class="price-card--price-text">
                <div class="price-card--price-number toggle-price-content odometer" data-price-monthly="18.71" data-price-yearly="224.52">18.71</div>
            </div>
```

Code for the input range

```
            <p> Number of users </p>
        <div class="range">
          <input type="range" id="slider2" min="1" max="5" steps="1" value="1">
        </div>
        <!-- <span id="slider_value"></span> -->
        <ul class="range-labels">
          <li class="active selected">1</li>
          <li>2-20</li>
          <li>21-99</li>
          <li>100-999</li>
          <li>1000+</li>
        </ul>
```

js

```
     function togglePriceContent() {
        if ($(toggleSwitch).is(":checked") === true) {
            // if toggle is yearly
            $(".toggle-price-content").each(function() {
                $(this).html($(this).data("price-yearly"));
            });
        } else {
            // if toggle is monthly
            $(".toggle-price-content").each(function() {
                $(this).html($(this).data("price-monthly"));
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Do you have more code and what do you want exactly

Comment: change the monthly/yearly price according to the range input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. Just test it with 2-20 on the range. I assume 10% discount.

```js
var sheet = document.createElement('style'),
  $rangeInput = $('.range input'),
  prefs = ['webkit-slider-runnable-track', 'moz-range-track', 'ms-track'];

document.body.appendChild(sheet);

var getTrackStyle = function(el) {
  var curVal = el.value,
    val = (curVal - 1) * 24.666666667,
    style = '';

  // Set active label
  $('.range-labels li').removeClass('active selected');

  var curLabel = $('.range-labels').find('li:nth-child(' + curVal + ')');

  curLabel.addClass('active selected');
  curLabel.prevAll().addClass('selected');

  // Change background gradient
  for (var i = 0; i < prefs.length; i++) {
    style += '.range {background: linear-gradient(to right, #37adbf 0%, #37adbf ' + val + '%, #fff ' + val + '%, #fff 100%)}';
    style += '.range input::-' + prefs[i] + '{background: linear-gradient(to right, #37adbf 0%, #37adbf ' + val + '%, #b2b2b2 ' + val + '%, #b2b2b2 100%)}';
  }

  return style;
}

$rangeInput.on('input', function() {
  sheet.textContent = getTrackStyle(this);
});

// Change input value on label click
$('.range-labels li').on('click', function() {
  var index = $(this).index();

  $rangeInput.val(index + 1).trigger('input');

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#range").change(function() {
    console.log($(".range-labels li.active").text());
    var user = $(".range-labels li.active").text();
    if (user == "2-20") {
      var second = $('#standard').data('price');
      console.log(second);
      var discount = second - (second * 0.10);
      console.log(discount);
      $('#standard').text(discount.toFixed(2));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.range {
     position: relative;
     width: 300px;
     height: 5px;
}
 .range input {
     width: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     top: 2px;
     height: 0;
     -webkit-appearance: none;
}
 .range input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     width: 14px;
     height: 14px;
     margin: -3px 0 0;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background: #37adbf;
     cursor: pointer;
     border: 0 !important;
}
 .range input::-moz-range-thumb {
     width: 14px;
     height: 14px;
     margin: -3px 0 0;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background: #37adbf;
     cursor: pointer;
     border: 0 !important;
}
 .range input::-ms-thumb {
     width: 14px;
     height: 14px;
     margin: -3px 0 0;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background: #37adbf;
     cursor: pointer;
     border: 0 !important;
}
 .range input::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
     width: 100%;
     height: 8px;
     cursor: pointer;
     background: #b2b2b2;
     border-radius: 3px;
}
 .range input::-moz-range-track {
     width: 100%;
     height: 8px;
     cursor: pointer;
     background: #b2b2b2;
     border-radius: 3px;
}
 .range input::-ms-track {
     width: 100%;
     height: 8px;
     cursor: pointer;
     background: #b2b2b2;
     border-radius: 3px;
}
 .range input:focus {
     background: none;
     outline: none;
}
 .range input::-ms-track {
     width: 100%;
     cursor: pointer;
     background: transparent;
     border-color: transparent;
     color: transparent;
}
 .range-labels {
     margin: 18px -41px 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
}
 .range-labels li {
     position: relative;
     float: left;
     width: 75.25px;
     text-align: center;
     color: #b2b2b2;
     font-size: 14px;
     cursor: pointer;
    /* &::before {
         position: absolute;
         top: -25px;
         right: 0;
         left: 0;
         content: "";
         margin: 0 auto;
         width: 9px;
         height: 9px;
         background: #b2b2b2;
         border-radius: 50%;
    }
    */
}
 .range-labels .active {
     color: #37adbf;
}
 .range-labels .selected::before {
     background: #37adbf;
}
 .range-labels .active.selected::before {
     display: none;
}
 body, html {
     height: 100%;
}
 body {
     background: #f2f2f2;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="range">
    <input id="range" type="range" min="1" max="5" steps="1" value="1">
  </div>

  <ul class="range-labels">
    <li class="active selected">
    1</li>
    <li>2-20</li>
    <li>21-99</li>
    <li>100-999</li>
    <li>1000+</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div data-price="18.71"id="standard">18.71</div>
<div data-price="30.71" id="premium">30.71</div>
<div data-price="41.21" id="enterprise">41.21</div>
```

Comment: sorry i wasnt being clear, but there is price table https://fonexinc.com/standard-pricing-structure/